# Count distinct values in a queue

Tags: python, queue

I am trying to implement the method that counts the number of distinct values in a queue.
For example, if the queue looks like this: [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 10], then the method should return 5.

So I create the function like this:

```
def count_distinct(self) -> int:

        # Test case
        Q = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11]

        if Q.is_empty():
            return 0
        
        count = 1
        current = Q.dequeue()
        
        while (Q.is_empty() is False):

            next = Q.dequeue()

            if current != next:
                count += 1
            
            current = next

        return count
```

But, the result was weird.

Expected result: 9

My result: 15

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks

Comment: `Q` is a list. `list` objects do not have `dequeue` or `is_empty` methods. Your code as posted will not run. Please provide a valid example.

Comment: In python, `next` is a reserved keyword. Instead, try renaming `next` to something like `next_value`. Moreover, your code seems to work as is when I sub in your `dequeue` and `is_empty` with `list.pop` and `len(list) == 0`. Please provide a complete example.

Comment: Are you writing your own functions - ```is_empty()``` and ```dequeue()``` ? If yes, please check those functions as well. Your code will give answer as 9 if these functions work as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just out of curiosity

Why don't you use `set` and get the length? Set only holds the unique values, and you don't seem to be concerned about any particular order these values appear.

```py
>>> len(set(Q))
9
```

Comment: May be the OP wants to have O(1) Space (*See the Queue is sorted*).

Answer (score 1):

Is queue like python queue.Queue?

If Queue is **ordered**, your function look right.

```py
import queue

def count_distinct() -> int:

    # Test case
    Q = queue.Queue()
    for x in [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11]:
        Q.put(x)

    if Q.empty():
        return 0
    
    count = 1
    current = Q.get()
    
    while (Q.empty() is False):

        next = Q.get()

        if current != next:
            count += 1
        
        current = next

    return count
```

It return 9.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Counter` from itertools:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 10]
c = Counter(l)
```

```
>>> len(c)
5
```

For your test case:

```
>>> len(Counter(Q))
9
```

Comment: You can just as well use a `set` and you get nicer code. `len(set(Q))` but this does not explain what issues are seen with the original code.

Comment: @rdas. Are you sure? If I shuffle the list, the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just first sort and then count the number unless it is not the same as the previous one.

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 10]
a = sorted(a)

last = a[0]
count = 1

for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] == last: 
        continue
    last = a[i]
    count += 1

print(count)
```

In your case, let's assume that your code is running and you have customly made all these extra methods(dequeue and etc.). In this case, most probably the reason is that your list is getting **not sorted** as you have created it.